# Repopulate window with new layout

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm building a Qt (C++ with QML) app that I wish to deploy across
multiple platforms, including desktop and mobile.

I've run into a difficulty in that I haven't found any way to (possibly
simulate) replacing the contents of the current (and only) application
window on an action (say a button press).

Note that I don't want to create a new window, I simply wish to change
the widgets shown in the current window.

For reference, a QML stub for the main window is shown below

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow
    ---
    ---
    toolBar: ToolBar { // Should be replaced on button click (eg: new)
        ---
        ---
    }
    ListView { // I need a way to replace this with a new sub-window
        id: listView
        model: myModel
        ---
        ---
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`StackView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html) component as well as a [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) for that.

The former is a good way to let the user move within the pages that compose your app, the latter indeed does exactly what you asked for (replace the content of the window).

The documentation already contains good examples of use for both components.